# Tring to send formdata with xhr but it send me a empty string on server side

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

If make this request, server-side NodeJS shows an **empty string**. I also try with **remove header**
but result same empty string **result like {}**.
I think formData append problem. here text and files are perfectly loaded.

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
//get username and pass from old url
let oldUrl = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams
let username = oldUrl.get('username')
let password = oldUrl.get('Password')

//set user and pass
let url = "/new_post_request_from_user?username=" + username + "&Password=" + password

xhr.open('POST', url, true);
xhr.onload = function () {
    let response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
    console.log(response)
}

let text = document.querySelector('[name=text]').value;
let files = document.querySelector('[name=imges]').files;

let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('text',text)
formData.append('picture', files[0]);

xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
xhr.send(formData);
console.log(...formData)
return false;
```

Here is my html/pug code

```
   textarea(type="text" placeholder='Post new think' name='text' required)
   input(type="file" name='imges' required)
   input(type="submit" value="Post" id="post")
```

****Any idea, how to solve it ?****

Comment: What does the Node.js code for parsing the body look like? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: Aside, you should not send a password in the request parameters, because then anyone who looks at the address bar or in the browser's history will be able to see it.